# AMPL implement ILP-formulation

Tags: ampl

I try to solve a Prize-Collecting-Steiner-Tree-Optimization problem with AMPL. I did find an ILP formulation for that, but now I have problems to implement that into AMPL. Specially the constraint in (c). [ILP-formulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1osd.png) I hope somebody can help me.

my try:

```
param n; #Anzahl der Knoten

set V := 1..n; #Knotenmenge
set E within {i in V, j in V: i<j}; #Kantenmenge
set T {i in V}; #Terminalmenge 

param p {i in V};
param w {(i,j) in E};
param r in V;


var x {(i,j) in E} binary;
var y {k in V: k != r} binary;

maximize profit: sum {i in V} p[i]*y[i] - sum {(i,j) in E} w[i,j]*x[i,j];

subject to Verhältnis: sum {(i,j) in E} x[i,j] = sum {i in V} y[i] - 1 ;
subject to Terminal{i in T}: y[i] = 1;
```

Comment: Pasting your code here would help you get answers instead of posting the images.

Comment: Can you clarify what, specifically, is causing you problems?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that the following works, but maybe will help you to get going

```
set Vt within V     #Vt subset of V
set card(Vt) >= 2   #|Vt| >= 2
set v in Vt
set E_Vt --> "maybe set similar as E but with Vt"

subject to constraint_C: sum{(i,j) in E_Vt} x[i,j] <= sum{i in Vt and i<>v} y[i]
```

I myself do not know how to write 
`i in Vt\{v}` this is why I wrote `i<>v` and am quite interested if you found a solution.